# DefaultGrailsPluginManager Issue on run-app it is giving me this error

Tags: grails

```
| Running Grails application
| Error 2013-05-15 22:37:49,943 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager  - Error configuring dynamic methods for plugin [resources:1.1.6]: String index out of range: 39
Message: String index out of range: 39
    Line | Method
->> 1907 | substring                     in java.lang.String
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    412 | relativeTo                    in org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceMeta
|    352 | relativeToWithQueryParams . . in     ''
|     57 | doCall                        in org.grails.plugin.resource.CSSRewriterResourceMapper$_map_closure1
|     60 | doCall . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.grails.plugin.resource.CSSLinkProcessor$_process_closure1
|     55 | process                       in org.grails.plugin.resource.CSSLinkProcessor
|     36 | map . . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.grails.plugin.resource.CSSRewriterResourceMapper
|    139 | invoke                        in org.grails.plugin.resource.mapper.ResourceMapper
|    128 | invokeIfNotExcluded . . . . . in     ''
|    587 | applyMappers                  in org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor
|    533 | prepareResource . . . . . . . in     ''
|    602 | doCall                        in org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor$_prepareSingleDeclaredResource_closure12
|     29 | addDeclaredResource . . . . . in org.grails.plugin.resource.util.ResourceMetaStore
|    600 | prepareSingleDeclaredResource in org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor
|    649 | prepareResourceBatch . . . .  in     ''
|    804 | resourcesChanged              in     ''
|    800 | loadModules . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|   1056 | reloadAll                     in     ''
|    172 | doCall . . . . . . . . . . .  in ResourcesGrailsPlugin$_closure3
|    334 | innerRun                      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker                     in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run                           in java.lang.Thread
| Server running. Browse to ......../MyApp
```

Comment: If you upgraded your Grails installation, make sure that you're using a version of the resources plugin which is up to date and compatible.

Comment: I have tried with creating new project in the GGTS-3.2 and it is giving same error

Comment: I am using grails 2.2.1 and resources plugin 1.1.6

Comment: Try the latest version `1.2.RC2`.

Comment: Tried upgrading resources plugin but 
unable to load resources error

 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceProcessor  - Unable to load resources
Message: String index out of range: 39
    Line | Method
->> 1907 | substring                     in java.lang.String
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    424 | relativeTo                    in org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceMeta
|    361 | relativeToWithQueryParams . . in     ''

Comment: @dmahapatro The latest version is 1.2. There's a bug in grails.org that doesn't show the correct info.

Comment: @SérgioMichels Thanks for pointing it out, missed it in description of plugin.

Comment: @SaurabhDixit Try `grails clean && grails compile && grails run-app` once installed. If the problem persists then I think you have to revisit the way you have used the resources (CSS, Js etc).

Comment: @dmahapatro thanks a lot, I had resource issue, checked'em all and fixed it, one css was importing another and I had included both in the resources, that was causing the issue
Thanks